# Empty Reports in crystal report from datasets in c#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, crystal-reports-2010

I am working on crystal report, i am using data set in c#, i create them by wizard, after that i choose the crystal report and created a report through the same dataset, and wrote following code.

```
    String temp = "c:\\a.pdf";

    DataSet1 ad = new DataSet1();

    ReportDocument d = new ReportDocument();

    d.Load("c:\\CrystalReport2.rpt");

    d.SetDataSource(ad.Tables[0]);

    d.Refresh();
```

At table[0] my employee tables lies. Problem is i am getting empty reports.. although my table is pretty much populated with records.

Comment: how your records are populated when you just create an empty Dataset?

Comment: My dataset name is dataset1 which i created through wizard. I have records present in the table. I can preview them but getting empty reports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually solved the problem my self.. I was lacking the table names which i have to send to dataset while filling them. Because of difference of name of dataset and provided name they table was un able to be fetched so the reports were empty.